# Screen Scratch Repair - Early 2013 15" MacBook Pro w/ Retina Display

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, repair, scratches

:(  Not a good day.

I just cleaned the screen of my rMBP using my usual kit.  A lint free microfiber cloth and my [AM screen cleaning fluid](http://www.amdenmark.com/sort/engelsk/cleaning/80102/80102.html).

However there must have been a small particle of something nasty either on the screen itself or on the cloth (I always keep the cloth stored away to prevent this exact issue!) the scratch that is left on the screen is admittedly tiny (~2mm) but it is there, it is bugging me and I would like to get it sorted if possible.

I've been reading up on various methods that might help but nothing definitive.

**Toothpaste!**

The toothpaste method that is often mentioned is unsuitable for the matte Retina display as others have reported that it left the area around where they applied the toothpaste with a glossy effect as toothpaste is actually very abrasive.

**Pencil Eraser**

This method I'm really not sure about on a rMBP screen.  There is a write up on how to do this [here](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_4797533_repair-lcd-scratch.html).

**Displex**

I'm wondering if anyone has tried something like [Displex](http://www.displex.com/classic/uk/index.php) on a rMBP screen?

**Vaseline**

Honestly!  I've read this in a few places now that due to the composition of petroleum jelly this can actually "fill" the scratches and more or less hide the fact that there is a scratch in the glass.  [Vaseline Online](http://www.vaseline.co.uk/Product.aspx?Path=Consumer/OurProducts/PetroleumJelly)

**ScratchPro**

This appears to be a product destined for use on cars but looks like it could well be used on any glass in general. [ScratchPro Online](http://scratchprokit.com/scratchpro-for-cars.html)

If anyone has any experience with any of the above on a Retina display or any other advice I'd love to hear it.  I must admit that I'm shocked at how easy it was to scratch the screen with little to no pressure being applied.

Be careful people!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just got back from my local Apple Store after making an appointment with them yesterday.  Fears have been confirmed basically.

No recommended way of repairing a scratch on the Retina MacBook Pro.  The glass covering the screen is toughened by it's still glass at the end of the day.

:)

Cost of replacing the screen was quoted at £414 for parts, £24 for labour + VAT at 20% makes it a grand total of £525.60

Comment: 15" - says in the question title.

Answer (score 3):

https://youtu.be/4UpWfmpETg0 - video instruction.

He used PolyWatch Polish

Comment: Oh that is interesting indeed, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

As to the suitability of your suggested products (good research BTW): no, no, no, no and no.

I would agree that yes, people should be careful around objects that can scratch glass when applying pressure and rubbing the screen.

The retina displays have glossy clear glass covering the LCD panel itself, so you may not be able to re-polish it to your satisfaction. I wouldn't be surprised if the surface was treated to reduce glare, but can't point to a public specification other than the glass is "high quality" and "optically pure" in the various marketing materials and product announcement videos.

The scratch itself likely is the beginnings of a [fresnel lens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens) and will distort the pixels behind it. You might be able to fill it with a substance designed to mimic the refractive index of glass - but my experience is that people do more harm than already exists when trying to polish and/or fill gaps in Apple's clear glass panels.

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well, hence why I'd prefer to get a decent amount of research done before even thinking about doing anything about it, if indeed I end up doing any at all.

Comment: Do you have links to the substances you mention?

Comment: I won't select any since it depends on the size and location of the scratch. Any glass repair resin might be suitable, but if you apply to much, then you need a razor blade to scrape off the excess. You might also try a silicone grease if you don't mind the smudges to try filling in the scratch's jagged corners and lightly clean the grease from the surface. Not much different than vaseline or water to dampen the surface temporarily.

Comment: You know I was already considering some form of silicone.  I'm going to keep reading and wotnot before I even think about buying anything.  Whatever happens I'll keep this question updated with info on what I do and any outcomes :)  Razor blade sounds even scarier than doing nothing at all!!!

Comment: Just for info the scratch really is pathetically small, less than 2mm long, feels shallow it wouldn't even take 0.25ml of anything to plug it completely and it 3" from top and 3" from right side.  I keep remembering I've done it and I have to search for it.  Really nothing to worry about really other than I know it's there!